# java avoiding dead locks

Tags: java, multithreading

Our application (uses java) is quite complex and I have got the below sample tricky code which will be used in the multi-threaded environment.

Now the problem is when I run the below code (taken to run it as stand alone main), I am encountering dead locks.

**Location class:-**

```
public class Location implements Runnable {

    private final int id;

    private final int[] dependentLocationIds;

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public Location(int id, int[] dependentLocationIds) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dependentLocationIds = dependentLocationIds;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean blockLocation() {
        lock.lock();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean releaseLocation() {
        lock.unlock();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean occupy() {
        boolean occupationStatus = false;
        //order ids first
        Arrays.sort(dependentLocationIds);

        lock.lock();
        try {

            //below sleep temporarily added to track the progress slowly
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            //Check dependentLocations are NOT being modified concurrently
            for(int id : dependentLocationIds) {
                Location location = LocationHelper.getLocation(id);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": blocking required dependent location :"+id);
                location.blockLocation();
            }
            //the above blocked Locations will be released in leave()

            //complex business logic to check and then make occupationStatus to true
            occupationStatus = true;
            System.out.println(id + ": location occupied by:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(!occupationStatus) {
                lock.unlock();
            }
           //if occupationStatus is true, the lock will be released in leave()
        }
        return occupationStatus;
    }

    public boolean leave() {
        boolean leaveStatus = false;
        //order ids first
        Arrays.sort(dependentLocationIds);
        try {
            //below sleep temporarily added to track the progress slowly
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            //complex business logic to check and then make leaveStatus to true
            leaveStatus = true;

            //now release dependent locations in reverse order
            for(int i=dependentLocationIds.length; i>0;i--) {
                Location location = LocationHelper.getLocation(id);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": releasing required dependent location :"+id);
                location.releaseLocation();
            }

            System.out.println(id + ": location released by "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        return leaveStatus;
    }

    public void run() {
        occupy();
        //some business logic goes here
        leave();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Location> locations = LocationHelper.getLocations();

        for(Location location : locations) {
            //Each location runs in different threads here
            new Thread(location, "THREAD-"+location.getId()).start();
        }
    }
}
```

**LocationHelper class:-**

```
public class LocationHelper {

    private static final List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        int[] locationids1 = {2, 3, 4, 5};
        Location location1 = new Location(1, locationids1);
        locations.add(location1);

        int[] locationids2 = {1, 3, 4};
        Location location2 = new Location(2, locationids2);
        locations.add(location2);

        int[] locationids3 = {1, 2, 4};
        Location location3 = new Location(3, locationids3);
        locations.add(location3);

        int[] locationids4 = {3, 5};
        Location location4 = new Location(4, locationids4);
        locations.add(location4);

        int[] locationids5 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        Location location5 = new Location(5, locationids5);
        locations.add(location5);
    }

    public static List<Location> getLocations() {
        return locations;
    }

    public static Location getLocation(int id) {
        Location required = null;

        for(Location location : locations) {
            if(location.getId() == id) {
                required = location;
            }
        }
        return required;
    }
}
```

> The core requirement is when I am updating a particular 'Location'
>   object, NONE of the dependent 'Location' objects should be allowed to
>   change. So I am trying to lock the dependent objects as well, which is where the complexity arises.

**I have tried ordering the location objects based on the 'location id' (unique) and then lock the location object, to avoid the dead locks, but there is no luck.**

Could you please help on how this code can be modified to avoid the dead locks ?

How can I refactor the 'Location' class to eliminate the above mentioned complexity ? 
Or else, are there any other better design options (using concurrent api) for 'Location' class to simplify the above logic ? Please help.

Comment: Why would you not want to always unlock in your finally? If some other code is doing the unlocking, I strongly suggest refactoring that out.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: unlocking the dependent objects SHOULD be done as part of leave() only

Comment: You should release the locks in the *opposite* order you acquired them in.

Comment: no luck, tried in the reverse order while releasing

Comment: Are you unlocking when you call `leave()`?

Comment: yes, unlocking will be done inside leave()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125358/discussion-between-david-ehrmann-and-developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of rearranging but following the debug statements it appears this does waht you are attempting to accomplish. I gutted a bit of code for testing, and changed to Lists instead of arrays.

Location Class.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Location
    implements Runnable
{

  private final int id;

  private final List<Integer> dependentLocationIds;

  private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  private boolean isUnlocked = true;

  public Location(int id, List<Integer> dependentLocationIds)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.dependentLocationIds = dependentLocationIds;
    Collections.sort(dependentLocationIds);
  }

  public int getId()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public List<Integer> getDependentLocationIds()
  {
    return dependentLocationIds;
  }

  public boolean isUnlocked()
  {
    return isUnlocked;
  }

  public boolean blockLocation()
  {
    lock.lock();
    isUnlocked = false;
    System.out.printf("Location: %d occupied by: %s\n", this.getId(),
        Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return isUnlocked;
  }

  public boolean releaseLocation()
  {
    lock.unlock();
    isUnlocked = true;
    System.out.printf("Location: %d released by: %s\n", this.getId(),
        Thread.currentThread().getName());
    return isUnlocked;
  }

  public void occupy()
  {
    while (!LocationHelper.acquireLocks(this))
    {
      try
      {
        System.out.printf("Location: %d sleeping during occupy on: %s\n",
            this.getId(), Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Thread.sleep(1500);
      }
      catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    try
    {
      // below sleep added to track the progress slowly
      Thread.sleep(1000);

      System.out.printf("Location: %d doing something on: %s\n", this.getId(),
          Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      LocationHelper.releaseLocks(this);
    }
  }

  public void leave()
  {
    try
    {
      // below sleep added to track the progress slowly
      Thread.sleep(1000);

      System.out.printf("Location: %d is attempting to leave on: %s\n",
          this.getId(), Thread.currentThread().getName());
      LocationHelper.releaseLocks(this);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      LocationHelper.releaseLocks(this);
    }
  }

  public void run()
  {
    occupy();
    leave();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<Location> locations = LocationHelper.getLocations();

    for (Location location : locations)
    {
      // Each location runs in different threads here
      new Thread(location, "THREAD-" + location.getId()).start();
    }
  }
}
```

LocationHelper Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LocationHelper
{
  private static List<Location> holdsLocks = new ArrayList<Location>();

  private static final List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<>();

  private static int printLocks = 0;

  static
  {
    locations.add(new Location(1, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
    locations.add(new Location(2, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)));
    locations.add(new Location(3, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)));
    locations.add(new Location(4, Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5)));
    locations.add(new Location(5, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)));
  }

  public static List<Location> getLocations()
  {
    return locations;
  }

  public static Location getLocation(int id)
  {
    return locations.stream().filter(l -> l.getId() == id).findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
  }

  public static synchronized boolean acquireLocks(Location location)
  {
    if (printLocks % 5 == 0)
    {
      locations.stream()
          .forEach(l -> System.out.printf("Location: %d status: %s\n",
              l.getId(), String.valueOf(l.isUnlocked())));
    }
    List<Location> required = location.getDependentLocationIds().stream()
        .map(LocationHelper::getLocation).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // If not available fail to lock.
    if (required.stream().filter(l -> !l.isUnlocked()).count() > 0L)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      try
      {
        required.stream().forEach(Location::blockLocation);
        holdsLocks.add(location);
        return true;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        required.stream().forEach(Location::releaseLocation);
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  public static boolean releaseLocks(Location location)
  {
    if (!holdsLocks.contains(location))
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      List<Location> required = location.getDependentLocationIds().stream()
          .map(LocationHelper::getLocation).collect(Collectors.toList());

      try
      {
        required.stream().forEach(Location::releaseLocation);
        holdsLocks.remove(location);
        return true;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are at least thinking in my view and it is close to what I need to do. I am validating this and let you know again.

Comment: No problem, I hope this gets you where you are going!

Comment: The only problem is Location object locks are acquired randomly by the requested threads (after awaking from sleep), rather I need the lock allocation based on FIFO.

Comment: As that is a separate requirement unrelated to the deadlock question, it might be Ideal to accept my answer and post the updated code in a new question if it is something you cannot figure out on your own.

Answer (score 5):

> the problem is when I run the below code (taken to run it as stand alone main), I am encountering dead locks.

I am not at all surprised.  In fact, I cannot imagine how you expect your code to work.  You start a bunch of threads, and each one attempts to lock several of the five `Location` instances in the system.  All you need for a deadlock is for two threads to each lock one location that the other wants to lock.

For example, the first thread starts by locking location 1, and among the other locations it tries to lock is location 2.  The second thread starts by locking location 2, and among the others it tries to lock is location 1.  If each thread succeeds in acquiring its first lock before either tries to acquire its second lock then you're toast, and there are so many deadlock opportunities like this in your program that it's highly unlikely that the program would fail to deadlock.

The easiest solution would be to avoid trying to do all this locking in parallel.  Of course, then there would be no need for locking at all.  Alternatively, for this particular code (but maybe not your larger code) you could employ the read side of a `ReentrantReadWriteLock`, which permits multiple threads to acquire it at once.  On the other hand, this is again equivalent to no locking at all if no one ever acquires the associated write locks.

Ordering lock acquisition should also solve your problem, but doing so seems incompatible with the problem.  Specifically, I observe that each `Location` locks *itself* first, but then may need to also lock any combination of other locations, including those that sort earlier.  Supposing that that first locking is essential (i.e. that you cannot perform it as part of the subsequent sequence of locks) and that you cannot restrict `Locations` to lock only other locations with larger IDs, I really don't see a way to safely do this other than to serialize the runs of the `Location`'s.

Comment: I wanted to lock the dependent location objects because there SHOULD NOT be any writes to the dependent locations during occupy() operation of a Location. These locks are allowed to be released ONCE DONE with the leave()on the location object. This doesn't make any difference by changing to ReentrantReadWriteLock.

Comment: @developer, I'm not really concerned with why you want to perform the locking.  The point is that the structure of your dependency graph is not compatible with running multiple `Location`s in parallel if each one must lock itself first and then take out exclusive locks on all its dependencies.

Comment: Any suggestions on refactoring the Location class to support the parallelism ?

Comment: "serialize the runs of the Location" is NOT at all good option, I did not like at all, rather than fixing/solving the concurrency problem

Comment: @developer, again, if each `Location` must lock itself before locking its dependencies, then the structure of your dependency graph is not compatible with parallelism.  That is your concurrency problem: what you want to do cannot safely be done concurrently.  There is no refactoring that can fix it; you need to change the nature of the computation to enable it to run in parallel.  In particular, if each location can lock itself in proper sequence with locking all its dependencies, then that should avoid deadlocking.  If they must not do that then I don't see a solution other than serializing.

Comment: Please find the below answer from JynXXedRabbitFoot. That is what something I am looking for.

Comment: @developer, I am glad you found what you are looking for, if indeed you did.  I observe that the solution you cite depends on essentially what I described, by serializing lock acquisition (via a `synchronized` method).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of ordering looks OK, ordering must solve de deadlock problem. If you always acquire the locks in the same order you will be safe.

**However**, I noticed that you are ordering only the direct dependents. You should order ALL the dependents **recursively** before start locking. And the own instance should also **put itself** in the list to be ordered.

This way you will safely lock all the "dependency tree" for each Location.

For illustration only look at the following example.

```
public List<Integer> getDependentTreeLocationIds() {
    List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    getLocationIdsRecursively(ret);
    return ret;
}

private void getLocationIdsRecursively(List<Integer> foundLocations) {
    if (foundLocations.contains(this.id) {
        // avoid infinite loop in case of circular dependencies
        return;
    }
    foundLocations.add(this.id);
    for (int id : dependentLocationIds) {
        Location location = LocationHelper.getLocation(id);
        location.getLocationIdsRecursively(foundLocations);
    }
}
```

Also, consider Bollinger's answer regarding your algorithm choice. If your dependency trees are relatively small comparing to total of locations, it may be a valid choice. But beware that it will be a long path to get there from the point you are now.

Comment: I could not fully understand your point, can you modify the above code and provide the answer ?

Comment: I mean the Location should, before start locking, create a List, add itself (this) and all its direct AND indirect dependents. Than you sort the list. The indirect dependents are the dependents of each dependent, and each dependent of each dependent of each dependnt, and so on..., recursively.

Comment: It will need some refactoring, it's not a 1 line of code change.

Comment: Problem is nothing to do with ordering of locks.

Comment: @TedTrippin, *of course* the problem has to do with ordering of locks.  Its a deadlock problem.  It therefore has to with the relative order of lock and unlock operations performed by different threads, and that is closely related to the order of lock and unlock operations within each thread individually.

Comment: Ok, maybe the ordering is not *the only problem*, but his insight about the ordering is right, it is a key point for avoiding deadlocks.

Comment: @DGardim: What does getLocationIdsRecursively() do ? Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I already upvoted your answer. _of course_ Its not an order problem, its a timing problem as you made clear in your example :). DGardim is suggesting that somehow affecting the ordering will fix the problem. The only way ordering would be a contributing factor would be if there were no cyclic depencies.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two patterns that seem problematic.

First, and hopefully most straightforward,

```
public boolean occupy() {
    boolean occupationStatus = false;
    //order ids first
    Arrays.sort(dependentLocationIds);

    lock.lock();
    try {
        //bunch of stuff
    } finally {
        if(!occupationStatus) {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    return occupationStatus;
}
```

Always locking `lock` but not always unlocking it is weird.  It means the lock usage isn't encapsulated, and this can have unexpected or difficult to predict side effects.  You should always release locks in the reverse order you got them, think of them in a stack.

Second, you're nesting locks.  If you have multiple threads traversing this, you need to consider every permutation of holding and attempting to acquire locks.  This is inordinately complex.

I'd suggest setting up a master lock (static or singleton), and locking for each operation, then your lock acquisition can use `tryLock`, which fails fast if locked.  Example:

```
public boolean occupy() {
    boolean occupationStatus = false;
    masterLock.lock();
    try{
        //order ids first
        Arrays.sort(dependentLocationIds);

        if(lock.tryLock()){
            //handle already blocked
        }
        try {
            //bunch of stuff
        } finally {
            if(!occupationStatus) {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }finally{
        masterLock.unlock();
    }
    return occupationStatus;
}
```

It's also odd that you sort in the call to `occupy`, I'd do this in the constructor.

Comment: I didn't understand the benefits of adding the master lock.